# shoulda-matchers presence true on save

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, shoulda

model

```
class RecipeIngredient < ActiveRecord::Base
  validates :recipe_id, presence: true, on: :save
  validates :ingredient_id, presence: true, on: :save

  belongs_to :recipe
  belongs_to :ingredient

  has_many :quantities
 end
```

test

```
require 'spec_helper'

describe RecipeIngredient do
  it { should validate_presence_of(:recipe_id) }
  it { should validate_presence_of(:ingredient_id) }
    it { should belong_to(:recipe) }
    it { should belong_to(:ingredient) }

    context "valid" do
      subject { RecipeIngredient.new(recipe_id: 1, ingredient_id: 1) }
      it { should be_valid }
    end
end
```

returns

> Failures:
>
> 1) RecipeIngredient
>        Failure/Error: it { should validate_presence_of(:recipe_id) }
>          Did not expect errors to include "can't be blank" when recipe_id is set to nil, got error:
>        # ./spec/models/recipe_ingredient_spec.rb:4:in `block (2 levels) in '
>
> 2) RecipeIngredient
>        Failure/Error: it { should validate_presence_of(:ingredient_id) }
>          Did not expect errors to include "can't be blank" when ingredient_id is set to nil, got error:
>        # ./spec/models/recipe_ingredient_spec.rb:5:in `block (2 levels) in '

I don't understand why adding on: :save has broken this test

Answer (score -1, accepted):

First off, you don't need to put the `on: :save` clause.  That is the default and can be left off.

Comment: This is not true! What I mean is if you dont put on: :save your validatons will be ran when you run object.valid? if you put it, they won't be ran! So I still think this is an error from shoulda!